# How to pivot table on multiple date rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to pivot a SQL Server table whilst also grouping by the date column.

This is my example data:

| date | ref | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 07/06/21 | ref1 | 20 |
| 08/06/21 | ref1 | 2 |
| 09/06/21 | ref1 | 15 |
| 07/06/21 | ref2 | 54 |
| 08/06/21 | ref2 | 23 |

And how the result needs to be:

| ref | 07/06/21 | 08/06/21 | 09/06/21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ref1 | 20 | 2 | 15 |
| ref2 | 54 | 23 |  |

Is it possible to do this with a SQL Server `PIVOT`, or does it require something else to do the grouping?

The dates are dynamic as well and based on a date range.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try ?

Comment: Pivoting is a form of aggregation, so yes, you need a `GROUP BY`. Also if those dates aren't set in stone (which I doubt) you'll need a dynamic pivot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: Also, are you really using SQL Server 2008? It's been completely unsupported now for 2 years~.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I was unsure how to attempt it due to the dynamic date range. Turns out the dynamic pivot was indeed what I needed for this and the reason why a regular pivot was not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need dynamic pivot query to do this try below query

```
declare @columns varchar(max)='',@sql nvarchar(max);

Create table #temp (Name nvarchar(max));

insert into #temp select distinct date from tablename

SELECT @columns+=QUOTENAME(Name) + ',' from #temp
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);


set @sql='SELECT * FROM
(select ref,count,date from tablename) t

PIVOT(sum([count])
FOR [Dates] IN ('+@columns+')
) AS pivot_table'
EXEC (@sql)

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.REF,
SUM(
      CASE
         WHEN C.DATE='07/06/21' THEN C.COUNT ELSE 0 END
   )AS '07_06_21',
SUM(
      CASE
       WHEN C.DATE='08/06/21' THEN C.COUNT ELSE 0 END
   )AS '08_06_21',
SUM(
    CASE
       WHEN C.DATE='09/06/21' THEN C.COUNT ELSE 0 END
  )AS '09_06_21'
 FROM my_example_data AS C
 GROUP BY C.REF
```

You can always try this conditional aggregation-approach

Comment: Unfortunately the dates are dynamic, so this wouldn't work for me in this case, but thank you.

Comment: Then your way is "dynamic pivot" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ref, [07/06/21],[08/06/21],[09/06/21] FROM
(SELECT ref, date , [count] FROM tableName) t1
PIVOT  
(  
 SUM([count]) FOR [date] IN ([07/06/21],[08/06/21],[09/06/21])) AS t2
ORDER BY t2.ref
```

Comment: A good answer provides a description so the OP can learn, in addition to hopefully working code.